# Mapping values in JOLT and loop for corresponding IDs - adding json field values

Tags: arrays, json, mapping, transformation, jolt

I need to transform below Input JSON where the ID has multiple ORG_LVL_2 codes and it should fall under the same OrgUnits array, whereas in my spec a separate object is getting created.

Previous Input:

```
[
  {
    "id": "0000606800",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0053"
  },
  {
    "id": "0000606800",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0054"
  },
  {
    "id": "0000609480",
    "ORG_LVL_2": "Co0055"
  }
]
```

Below Spec:

```
[
  { // partition by "id" values while hardcoding for the attributes "ORG_LVL_1" and "C01"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "id": "@1,id.&",
        "O*": {
          "#ORG_LVL_1|$": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitLevel",
          "#C01|@": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitCode"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // dissipate each component of the independent arrays to their respective indexes 
    // in order to generate the desired objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "#test": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
        "$": ["IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
"IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountCode"],
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "*": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#4].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment[&2].orgUnitDetails[&].&1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of redundantly generated null values
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

There's minor modification in the input instead of ORG_LVL_2 its "LVL2" but we need the same output in orgUnits:

Input:

```
[
    {
        "id": "0000606800",
        "status": "Active",
        "name": "Office Supplies",
        "LVL2": "Co0053"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000606800",
        "status": "Active",
        "name": "Office Supplies",
        "LVL2": "Co0054"
    },
    {
        "id": "0000609480",
        "status": "Active",
        "name": "Office Supplies",
        "LVL2": "Co0055"
    }
]
```

Additionally, in the output along with the id, I want to display "name" as "glAccountDescription" and same as "glAccountName", and "id" value in "referenceCodeForEntity" and "integrationTrackingNumber" required output as below:

```
{
    "IntegrationEntities": {
        "integrationEntity": [
            {
                "integrationEntityHeader": {
                    "referenceCodeForEntity": "0000606800",
                    "integrationTrackingNumber" : "0000606800"
                },
                "integrationEntityDetails": {
                    "glAccount": {
                        "id": "0000606800",
                        "status": "ACTIVE",
                        "glAccountName": "Office Supplies",
                        "glAccountDescription": "Office Supplies",
                        "glAccountCode": "0000606800",
                        "glAccountTypeId": "GLTYPE001",
                        "orgUnits": {
                            "orgUnitAssignment": [
                                {
                                    "orgUnitDetails": [
                                        {
                                            "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_1",
                                            "orgUnitCode": "C01"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_2",
                                            "orgUnitCode": "Co0053"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "orgUnitDetails": [
                                        {
                                            "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_1",
                                            "orgUnitCode": "C01"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "orgUnitLevel": "ORG_LVL_2",
                                            "orgUnitCode": "Co0054"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've developed this spec with the help of Barbaros Ozhan, which is currently meeting the expected outcome, if there's way to minimize code, please feel free to suggest. Thank you

```
[
    { // generate new attribute, namely "ORG_LVL_2"
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "ORG_LVL_2": "@(1,LVL2)"
            }
        }
 },
    { // delete the original attribute
        "operation": "remove",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "LVL2": ""
            }
        }
 },
    { // partition by "id" values while hardcoding for the attributes "ORG_LVL_1" and "C01"
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "id": "@1,id.&",
                "name": "@1,id.&",
                "O*": {
                    "#ORG_LVL_1|$": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitLevel",
                    "#C01|@": "@2,id.&2.orgUnitCode"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { // dissipate each component of the independent arrays to their respective indexes 
        // in order to generate the desired objects
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "*": {
                "$": [
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountCode",
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber"
                ],
                "#0010": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountTypeId",
                "name": [
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountName",
                    "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountDescription"
                ],
                "#ACTIVE": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#2].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.status",
                "*": {
                    "*": {
                        "*": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[#4].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits.orgUnitAssignment[&2].orgUnitDetails[&].&1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { // get rid of redundantly generated null values
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
        }
},
    {
        "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
        "spec": {
            "IntegrationEntities": {
                "integrationEntity": {
                    "*": {
                        "integrationEntityDetails": {
                            "glAccount": {
                                "glAccountName": "=firstElement(@(1,&))",
                                "glAccountDescription": "=firstElement(@(1,&))"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
},
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "IntegrationEntities": {
                "integrationEntity": {
                    "*": {
                        "integrationEntityHeader": {
                            "integrationTrackingNumber": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&2].integrationEntityHeader.integrationTrackingNumber",
                            "referenceCodeForEntity": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&2].integrationEntityHeader.referenceCodeForEntity",
                            "additionalInfo": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&2].integrationEntityHeader.additionalInfo"
                        },
                        "integrationEntityDetails": {
                            "glAccount": {
                                "id": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.id",
                                "status": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.status",
                                "glAccountName": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountName",
                                "glAccountDescription": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountDescription",
                                "glAccountCode": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountCode",
                                "glAccountTypeId": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountTypeId",
                                "parentGlAccountId": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.parentGlAccountId",
                                "orgUnits": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.orgUnits",
                                "glAccountErpId": "IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.[&3].integrationEntityDetails.glAccount.glAccountErpId"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
]
```